# If it's not an Ember component, what is it?

Tags: ember.js

I have an Ember template `.hbs` file with its controller and route. I do not have a `component.js` file for it. What is an Ember `not-quite-component` called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just named it.  "Controller", "Route" and "Template".  The template belongs to the controller and the controller belongs to the route.  A default controller is magically provided for you if you do not define one, and an empty template is also provided by default.  If you are speaking to someone and need to convey what you have, the route can somewhat be assumed since it is the only thing absolutely required to reach a page, thus you can simply say "my controller".

Answer (score 1):

When you type a URL into your browser, the [Ember Router](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.10.0/routing/) has a route, or routes, that handle that particular URL.

The [Route](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.10.0/routing/defining-your-routes/) can render a template, assign a model, handle actions, redirect to a new route, etc.

A route's associated [Controller](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.10.0/controllers/) can be customized if needed, to handle actions or custom properties, for instance.

If the route renders a [Template](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.10.0/templates/handlebars-basics/), a component might then be called in the template, or it might not.

A [Component](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.10.0/components/defining-a-component/) typically encapsulates HTML mark-up and functionality that is intended for reusability in some fashion, or to isolate a subset of concerns. If no JavaScript is needed, a component template can be used individually. If JavaScript is required for additional functionality, a component subclass for the component template would also be necessary.

You could say a controller is "not quite a component", given that it behaves in much the same way as a component. However, the template a controller is associated with, is rendered by its route.